# How to list available loggers?

Tags: ros, rosconsole, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a `rosconsole.config` file and the `ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable to specify where it is, but is there any way to get a list of available loggers without having to run rqt_logger_level?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88276/how-to-list-available-loggers?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know you want a solution without rqt_logger_level. Although I still refer to it, this answer doesn't depend on it.

Get a list of node names by `rosnode list`. Then, as in `rqt_logger_level.LoggerLevelServiceCaller.send_logger_change_message`, you can iteratively [call rosservice.get_service_class_by_name](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/groovy-devel/rqt_logger_level/src/rqt_logger_level/logger_level_service_caller.py#L114) to get a corresponding service to the given `node` name.

HTH.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-10-11**:
That looks great, thanks. The larger fix is probably to develop a curses-based rosconsole client—especially one capable of prepopulating from the roslaunch-logs dir and spitting out a rosconsole.config file which you can then point to from the ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE env var.